# How to take file from button

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I made a application with iTextSharp to put numbers on a PDF file.
As you will see in the following code, my application just can do this, only if the file is in a specific directory.

So I made an "Other" button where the user can select a file.
What I want to do now is, that the chosen file will download the converted PDF.

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace NummerierePDF
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"L:\Users\user\Documents\PDFnummerieren\PDF.pdf");
            iTextSharp.text.Font blackFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
                using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream))
                {
                    int pages = reader.NumberOfPages;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
                    {
                        ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetOverContent(i), Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, new Phrase(i.ToString(), blackFont), 568f, 15f, 0);
                    }
                }
                bytes = stream.ToArray();
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"L:\Users\user\Documents\PDFnummerieren\PDF1.pdf", bytes);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var FD = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
            if (FD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string fileToOpen = FD.FileName;

                System.IO.FileInfo File = new System.IO.FileInfo(FD.FileName);



                System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileToOpen);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

So `File.WriteAllBytes(@"L:\Users\user\Documents\PDFnummerieren\PDF1.pdf", bytes);`
can stay because it doesn't matter where the file will be downloaded after it's converted.

But `File.ReadAllBytes(@"L:\Users\user\Documents\PDFnummerieren\PDF.pdf");`
shouldn't be a specific directory, it should get the chosen file from button3.
As you probably noticed I'm new into programming so I thought maybe I could do this:  `File.ReadAllBytes(fileToOpen);`
to get the string. Though that doesn't do his job.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-open-files-using-the-openfiledialog-component).

Comment: Yeah.. I don't get it. What means "expect you having button control" ? and the EventHandler should be in my button1 ?

Comment: It seems that you just need a class level variable where to store the filename selected in the button3 event handler. Just declare _string theFile = "";_ inside your class, then set it in the button3 event handler instead of the local variable and finally use this _theFile_ in your button1 event handler replacing the current hard coded path. Of couse you will need to add some safety check before using that variable like verifying if it has been initialized by button3

Comment: like this: https://pastebin.com/AZm63R1w ? But i get: "Error 1 The name 'theFile' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: No that's not a class level variable..... giving you an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a variable between methods of the same class then you need to declare a private and non-static class level variable (called also Instance Field). This is visible to every method of the class.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Here declare a variable visible to all methods inside the class but 
    // not outside the class. Init it with an empty string
    private string theFile = "";

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // When you click the button1 check if the variable 
        // has been set to something in the button3 click event handler
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(theFile) || !File.Exists(theFile))
            return;

        // Now you can use it to load the file and continue with the code
        // you have already written
        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(theFile);
        ......
        ......
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // The only job of button3 is to select the file to work on
        // as you can see we can use the variable also here
        var FD = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
        if (FD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            theFile = FD.FileName;
    }
}
```

But do you really need a separate button for this? I mean you could put the three lines of code in the button3 directly in at the start of the code in button1 and remove the superfluos (at this point) button3

I suggest you to read some docs on variable's Scope and Lifetime

Comment: That solved my problem, thanks! But when I upload bigger PDF files I get a MemoryException error. What can I do about that ?

Comment: I suggest you to post a new question with details about this error. More people will look at it than here and you will follow the rules about a single question at time

Comment: @Steve "class level variable" is somewhat odd terminology, because "class level" suggests that the variable is shared between different object instances of the same class, which is not the case in your example. What you mean is an "instance field".

Comment: @WimCoenen I get what you mean, but it is so common to call them in that way. I never thought to differentiate between _local_ class level and _static_ class level, but I suppose you have a point here.

Comment: I don't think instance fields are actually commonly called that; If I google "class level variable", I end up at [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_variable) or [this stackexchange post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/293478/what-are-the-differences-between-class-variables-and-instance-variables-in-java) which seem to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace NummerierePDF
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string fileToOpen = string.Empty;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileToOpen)) return;

            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileToOpen);
            iTextSharp.text.Font blackFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
                using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream))
                {
                    int pages = reader.NumberOfPages;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
                    {
                        ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetOverContent(i), Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, new Phrase(i.ToString(), blackFont), 568f, 15f, 0);
                    }
                }
                bytes = stream.ToArray();
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"L:\Users\user\Documents\PDFnummerieren\PDF1.pdf", bytes);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var FD = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
            if (FD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                fileToOpen = FD.FileName;

                System.IO.FileInfo File = new System.IO.FileInfo(FD.FileName);



                System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileToOpen);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have put your variable to class scope and now you can access it from anywhere inside your class